# Unmarried man teacher of children

Tags: halacha, minhag, marriage, employment

I see from
The [Shulchan Aruch Even Ezer 22.20](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7598) and from
[Shulchan Aruch Harav, Hilchois Talmud Torah, perek 1 halocho 13](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/13)
that single man should not be a teacher of children (under 13) becouse of the mothers (woman) that bring the children

What is the practice in different communities?

If it is permitted, what are the sources?

Comment: The primary concern is one of yichud, as the mothers of the young children bring their kids to school. The easy solution is to segregate drop-off/pick-up environments from the teachers, and that all interactions with parents be with either both parents, or the same sex as the teacher.

Comment: @isaackotlick what is the source that the problem is yichud, from the source I brought your solution helps except the part of both parents

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't open the link in your question. I may be able to find the source for my comment later today, though...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky That doesn't sound like a very "easy solution."

Comment: @Daniel Most modern schools don't have the parents bringing the childre directly INTO the classrooms except on occassion where there are a number of students and parents already present. When drop-off is in the front of the school, the mother is never secluded with the teacher.

Comment: @isaackotlicky thank you for telling me, I fixed the link

Comment: Perhaps for the safety of the children as well? Nowadays all possibilities need to be taken into account.

Comment: @alicefine being married will not help with this, but it is good to be strict with yihud see shulchan aruch even ezer 24,

Comment: @Isaackotlicky I found it, yichud is a problem by a GIRL teacher that is not married, even ezer 22.20 מי שאין לו אשה לא ילמד תינוקת מפני שאמות הבנים באות לבית הספר לבניהם ונמצא מתגרה בנשים וכן אשה לא תלמד קטנים מפני אבותיהם שהם באים בגלל בניהם ונמצאו מתייחדין עמה ואין המלמד צריך שתהיה אשתו שרויה עמו בבית הספר אלא היא בביתה והוא מלמד במקומו:

Comment: @isaacmoses most of shulchan aruch harav is from before him see privius comment from even ezer 22.20. http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7598

Comment: @isaacmoses thank you I will edit the question